# Window 10 IE 11 Enterprise option not working for legacy Url

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11, ie8-compatibility-mode, ie11-developer-tools

Legacy URl not working with enterprise mode ON in IE 11 after upgrade to Windows 10

Legacy URl not working with "enterprise mode ON" in IE 11 after upgrade to Windows 10

When I open legacy url in IE 11 and checked enterprise mode option, application does not work as expected. However it used to work earlier with window 8 IE 11 compatibility settings. It seems turning enterprise mode on does not having any effect

Please let me know if any one has faced this issue and is there any configuration which need to be done ?

Comment: Can you please inform us which OS build and which update you are using currently for your Windows 10 OS? If possible than try to check for the latest Windows update and install it if any available. Than again try to make a test to check whether it helps to solve the issue or not. Ref: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/04/08/windows-10-tips-enabling-enterprise-mode-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: version 1709 (OS Build 16299.1087)

Comment: So did you check for the latest updates? If yes, did it help? If possible for you than can you inform us whether you are seeing the logo for the enterprise mode beside the address bar or not? You can also inform us, What exact is not working. It can give better idea about the issue.